# how integer type can handle text stream (getchar()) in C?

Tags: c, buffers

While going through C programming by Ritchie and kernighan, I came across the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int t;
    t = getchar();
    while ((t=getchar()) != EOF) {
            putchar(t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand how can a integer type variable c , be used to handle buffered text stream,

delimited by newline or ctrl-D,

When I tried for ,
`printf("%d",getchar());`

it's giving me `ASCII` value of only first character, but here `t` seems to be manipulating the whole `buffer` until I press enter,

and when I press `ctrl-D` in between line it just copies the previous buffer content.

does it mean `ctrl-D` is a `delimiter` as well as `EOF'?
Can someone please explain me the logic behind it?

Comment: Try this on StackOverflow. I bet you'll get an answer very quickly...

Comment: sorry, but I am unable to ask questions in stackoverflow, otherwise I would have asked in stackOverflow , can I post it on any other stack exchage group apart from stackOverflow.

Comment: Do not post off-topic content on a site in an [attempt to circumvent a question block on another site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/lets-help-askers-who-are-trying-to-circumvent-question-block-at-stack-overflow). This is not an appropriate question here - if you wish to get out of the block on Stack Overflow, please read the linked article that appears on the block message. You know, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the operating system handles the buffered text stream.  It does this for a variety of reasons, mostly for performance, but also to support features like inline editing.

Your program is sleeping until you either press enter or ctrl-D.  At that point, the entire line is passed to your programs input stream.  Then each getchar call will retrieve only one character from that stream at a time and return it in t.  As long as there is input available, getchar will immediately return with the first character of that data.

So the next question is what happens when the string runs out.  Assuming you haven't indicated end of file with ctrl-D, getchar will then block while waiting for user input, and your program again sleeps while the operating system gets back to work.

So, `t` isn't manipulating the whole line, the operating system is, and `t` hasn't yet been assigned at this point, because getchar hasn't returned yet.

Comment: thanx @caveman, now I got it , that operating system is manipulating the buffers ,and we have taken int type so that EOF can be captured through -1 value defined at <stdio.h>.